# How do I capture the number of times SIGINT is used in c?

Tags: c, function

How do I capture the number of times SIGINT is used before the program ends??
For example: In a program that only ends when the SIGQUIT is used, and tells us how many times the user I pressed ctr-c (used SIGINT) before ending.

I have made this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd>

void sigproc1(int var); 
void sigproc2(int var);

int main()
{

    signal(SIGINT, sigproc1)  //SIGINT - interactive attention request sent to the program.
    signal(SIGQUIT, sigproc2) //SIGQUIT - The SIGQUIT signal is similar to SIGINT, except that it's controlled by a different key—the QUIT character, usually C-\—and produces a core dump when it terminates the process, just like a program error signal. You can think of this as a program error condition “detected” by the user.


}

void sigproc1(int var)
{

    signal(SIGINT, sigproc1);
    signal(SIGINT, sigproc2);

    printf("You have pressed ctrl-c\n");

    //Save the number of times that it received the SIGINT signal
//Print the number of times that it received the SIGINT signal
}

void sigproc2(int var)

    exit(0); //Normal exit status.
}
```

Comment: static variable maybe?

Comment: @TomerArazy, but how do i capture the SIGINT in a static variable?? 
Normally i would do something like:

    static int x = 0; // x is initialized only once across three     calls of func()
    printf("%d\n", x); // outputs the value of x
    x = x + 1;

But times time i want to catch  the number of times the signal is used and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @LuisQuesado  Increment the counter inside the handler (sigproc1) and print finally when you exit inside sigproc2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a global variable called `ct` (from count) that I increment and display in the `sigint` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int ct = 0;

void sigint(int sig)
{
    printf("You have pressed ctrl-c %d times\n", ++ct);
}

void sigquit(int sig){
    exit(0); // use CTRL+\ to exit the program since CTRL+c displays those stats
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigint);
    signal(SIGQUIT, sigquit);

    while(1){}
}
```

Sample output:

```
[paullik@eucaryota tmp]$ ./a.out 
^CYou have pressed ctrl-c 1 times
^CYou have pressed ctrl-c 2 times
^CYou have pressed ctrl-c 3 times
^CYou have pressed ctrl-c 4 times
^CYou have pressed ctrl-c 5 times
^CYou have pressed ctrl-c 6 times
^CYou have pressed ctrl-c 7 times
^CYou have pressed ctrl-c 8 times
^\[paullik@eucaryota tmp]$
```

Comment: Doesn't `ct` need to be locked or assigned using atomic operations?

Comment: Yes, I think it does need locking since multiple programs can send that signal at the same time, but it's out of the scope of this question/answer.